# Any way to disconnect animations after animating?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

I'm pretty new to blender, so don't judge me to harshly on my noob levels here, but lets get right to the question. Is there any way to disconnect animations after animating. Here's An example if you don't quite get what i'm saying. I have a player character model and a gun model both with separate skeletal meshes. I would like to animate the gun and the player character together in the same file (for more precise animations) then separate the two so I have the gun and player as two separate objects/skeletal meshes, and both objects have there parts of the animation. Is there any way to do this? If not, tell me the best alternative. Thanks for any response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you animate two separatedo objects (in example "sphere" and "cube"), two "actions" are created, named "SphereAction" and "CubeAction".
Turn a window into dopesheet and set the tiled menu from "dopesheet" to "Action editor": if you select an object you will see his action, wich can be copied, pasted, moved, muted, saved as "Fake" user, linked or appended in a new file, or even assigned to another object: it will work if all the names (of the bones) are the same.
Animation controls that search for a non existing object or bone are simply ignored.

[image]